# “Could not load unit UnitName symbol information for TClassName. Do you want to try to find this file yourself?”

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-xe

In a related post about "[Error Could not load unit [unit] symbol information for [TClassName]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061734/how-do-you-fix-could-not-load-unit-unitname-symbol-information-for-tclassname)", a solution was suggested that directories should be added to the Library Path of Delphi. However, this solution does not work for me.

Specifically, for Delphi XE or higher:

- The TBMDSpinEdit component was downloaded from [Mitov's website](http://mitov.com/free_downloads). A design-time package was created. The BMDSpinEdit.pas was added to the package. The package was compiled and installed. The installation was successful.
- The source and .dcu directories of TBMDSpinEdit were added to the Library Path.
- Then, an ActiveX Library project was created. The menu "File" -> "New" -> "Others" -> "ActiveX Control" was selected. In the ActiveX Control Wizard, the BMDSpinEdit component was selected, and error occurred when Enter was pressed.

Could you help me with this problem ?

Comment: Which delphi version?

Comment: @Johan Delphi XE and higher.

Comment: When you created the new package, are you sure you picked "Delphi package" instead of C++ Builder package and chose VCL framework? Worked for me with XE2.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I do not have C++ Builder. This is strange. You are successful for creating ActiveX control with TBMDSpinEdit, using the above procedure ? I just tried and failed again. Could you help to comment the possible reason ?

Comment: Status no-repro with D7.

Comment: @NGLN D7 is fine. Did you try DXE or higher ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do the ActiveX step. Doing that, I get the same error on XE2. Even when I browse to the DCU, the error remains.

Comment: This looks like a question for Embarcadero support, what do they say?

Comment: @Johan: I have a tight schedule, and have to start looking for other ways around right now (redesign, or other tools like C#).